# Screen flickering galaxy s3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, screen, hardware, kernel

I noticed that my galaxy s3 sometimes show flickering on display when I am for example closing apps. I disabled HW overlays but it didn't help. I read that it can cause battery. My battery is fairly old (2 years) and Can withstand 3 hours surfing net and listening to music on 1200 mhz.

How it can be battery? It's giving low voltage to CPU/GPU and that's why is graphical rendering so bad?

Or it causes kernel? I have custom. I never had stock so I don't know if on the stock it's OK.

I have archidroid based on CM11

**EDIT:** Here is video. Screen flickering on my phone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXPK9V9ENow&feature=youtu.be

[image]

Comment: I had this too on my S3 4G variant. The battery is the problem as it does not give out power consistently and suddenly just drops all power output. You have to replace the battery. The screen flickering is an indicator for a broken/completely used battery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you post this comment as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this too on my S3 4G variant. 

The battery is the problem as it does not give out power consistently and suddenly just drops all power output. You have to replace the battery.

> The screen flickering is an indicator for a broken/completely used battery.

Comment: But if it is battery, screen flickering should be visible also when screen is inactive, right?

Comment: I mean when screen is turned on but nothing is moving etc

Comment: I know. I had this, too. The screen just flickers, but the battery is at way more than 1 or 2%. This means that the battery is broken/worn out and you need to replace it.

Comment: I bought new battery but screen flickering is still showing :(

Comment: That's weird. For me it fixed any flickering. May be some damage to your screen eg. water or much dust.

Comment: Here is screen flickering on my phone >> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXPK9V9ENow&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I don't see any hardware related screen flickering. Maybe something is wrong with your ROM or one of your various modules you have installed. Battery-related screen flickering is way more visible and makes your screen gradually becoming darker until it's black.